# Clone() and MoveTo() not working (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm attempting to make a model move to a Vector3 position after cloning it with Clone() but neither seem to work.

```
local money = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Money
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

function Check()
if money < 3000 and money > 0 then
    local House = script.Parent.Houses.Crate:Clone()
    House:MoveTo(player.Homeloc.Value)
end
```

Comment: You know roblox has a forum for this stuff. People with more experience could probably help you there

Comment: Yeah but nobody seems to really bother to help you on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are setting Vector3, you need to do Vector3.new(). So in this case,

```lua
House:MoveTo(Vector3.new(player.Homeloc.Value))
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I had thought of that but I assumed that it created a completely new Vector3 when I already had one

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as correct if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be indexing the value property of money

```
if money.Value < 3000 and money.Value > 0 then
```

Oh and you're missing an `end`, in fact you should probably revisit Lua basics, this code looks like you ripped out pieces and segments of other code or free models and then tried to fit together a logical script when it fact it doesn't make sense.

Additionally, you need to **not** use a LocalScript for this. Moving objects around is a *server-sided* operation. I would recommend using FilteringEnabled.

Also, you should check for errors from now on.

By the way, why are you defining player *after* money, you should define it beforehand and then index it while defining money.

Comment: Ok then, but the MoveTo() is still not working even when it's not a local script.

Comment: I hope you're not trying to use LocalPlayer from a server script :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you need to fix fix with this script to get i up and running.

1st you never define "Homeloc" Homeloc must be a Vector3 value instance or a value created inside the script which also must be vector3.

2nd instead of using

```
MoveTo(player.Homeloc.Value)
```

try

```
MoveTo(Vector3.new(player.Homeloc.Value))
```

I don't know if I covered all the problems but that seems like most of it.